# How to pass Request object from route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, request

Following is my routes where I am calling my Controller directly in route.

How can I pass `Request $request` to my `getBlog` Function.. Or is there any way to directly get `$request` object in my `getblog` function of controller ???

```
$artObj = App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Front\ArticleController'); 
return $artObj->getBlog($id);
```

Code in Routes:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    // Get Id and Type depending on url 
    $resultarray = App\Model\UrlAlias::getTypefromUrl($slug);
    if(!empty($resultarray)) {
        if($resultarray[0]['type'] == 'article') {
            $id = $resultarray[0]['ref_id'] ;
            $artObj = App::make('App\Http\Controllers\Front\ArticleController');
            return $artObj->getBlog($id);
        } else {
            return Response::view("errors.404", $msg, 400);
        }
    } else {
        return Response::view("errors.404", array(), 400);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do in the head of the routes.php file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And then in the beginning of your route:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug, Request $request) {
```

And the $request will be available to you. But that is extremely bad practice. What you should do - is move the whole logic into the controller like that:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Front'], function(){
   Route::get('/{slug}', 'ArticleController@methodName'); 
});
```

and then you can use the Request class in your controller class and the controller method:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front

use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class ArticleController 
{ ...

   public function methodName(Request $request){
     ...function implementation...
   }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Dont have any other options so have to follow this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @SatishUpadhyay if that helped you - you can mark the response as the answer, so that other users would know which one helped.

Answer (score 2):

The Request is a global variable, you can access it anywhere with either php code or even some helper Laravel functions.

Just use `request()` and it's the same as passing the request as an object inside a variable through a function. (It's equivalent to the Request $request variable received).

It improved readability also. Just remember you can't change request objects directly, you'd better use request()->merge(['key' => 'newValue']);